# Android/iPhone “Add to Home Screen” url customization

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, bookmarks, homescreen

I have a website and when user adds it to home screen, it saves current url.

*For example:* if user is on example.com/categories page, application will save this url and when user opens application from home screen, it will opens example.com/categories.

I want to customize it in such a way that when user saves to home screen, **starting page always was home page (example.com)**

How can I achieve it ? is it possible?